# axios.create() successfully creates connection for System Administrator not other profile

Tags: soap-api, profile

I am creating a Salesforce api testing tool. How it works is I use jsforce.login(un,pw) to create a connection using their api:

```
var soap = new jsforce.Connection({
    oauth2: {
        loginUrl: userData.loginurl
    }
});

var loginResponse = await soap.login(userData.username, userData.password);
```

I know jsforce isn't entirely soap api but that's how I think of it.

Then I use the instanceURL and accessToken created on this object to create an axios object to make calls to Salesforce REST api that jsforce doesn't support:

```
   var rest = await axios.create({
        baseURL: soap.instanceUrl,
        timeout: 50000,
        headers: {
            'Authorization':`Bearer ${soap.accessToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Accept':'application/json'
        }
    });
```

This all works just fine for System Administrator users. However it's not working for a profile cloned from Standard Platform User that I called Standard Platform Tester. What happens is I get an axios error:

> ```
>    AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404
>        at settle (file:///Users/bisesma/sf-api-auto/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:19:12)
>        at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (file:///Users/bisesma/sf-api-auto/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:570:11)
>        at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:406:35)
>        at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
>        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
> ```

This profile has the API enabled system permission and basically any other permission with api in the description. Could this be a permission problem ? If so which one I can't find anything. If that is the problem why is it a 404 and not something more specific ?

Comment: Have you created Connected App in your org?